# Relight pilot on ideal standard boiler

Tags: boiler, pilot-light

I recently had to turn off the gas supply and the pilot light on the old boiler went out. The instructions mention turning the gas control knob to pilot position but it doesn't seem to turn. Pretty sure it is the white thing shown in the picture. Is there a knack to turning it?[image: picture]

Comment: You usually have to push down to turn it from "OFF" to "PILOT". Sometimes also to move from "PILOT" to "ON", sometimes that turn from "PILOT" to "ON" it will automatically pop back up.

Comment: You might also want to gently clean crud around it with dry toothbrush.

Comment: Thank you. I was away over Christmas but I had another go and managed to turn it but not enough as I am assuming it will press down at some point. I think it is just really stiff. I will try to follow your advice, really helpful